# How to parse a csv key value file using python

Tags: python

I have a requirement to parse a key value coma separated file.Please find attached the sample log file format .

```
event_1,log_time:2013-11-05T08:33:37:293+00,user_id:2535285332077170,profile_id:8,nickname:2535285332077170,rank_id:7,shop_tr_status:OK,
event_2,log_time:2013-11-05T08:33:37:344+00,rule_id:18372990742769963554,user_id:2535285332077170,profile_id:8,
event_3,log_time:2013-11-05T08:33:37:401+00,user_id:2535285332077170,profile_id:8,nickname:2535285332077170
```

My requirement is if it is event 1 then I need log_time and nickname

if it is event_2 then I need userid and profileid

if it is event_3 then i need userid and nickname

Can anyone suggest what is the best way to proceed with this

Answer (score 3):

Forget csv.reader. You should use [tablib](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/tutorial/#advanced-usage) with dynamic columns:

```
ds = tablib.Dataset()
ds.csv = open(csvfile).read()
```

Then you can add the columns with:

```
def event_data(row):
    if row[0] == 'event_1':
        return [row[1], row[4]]
    # .. and so forth

ds.append_col(event_data, header='Event data')
```

And getting that column should give you the data you want, according to the first column.

Comment: Definitely another good alternative especially if you don't have headers. Again, if you have headers DictReader is built into the csv package and you won't have to import tablib. But you should consider tablib if you don't have headers.

Comment: Even if you have headers, tablib is much, much easier to use and has other useful features. I never used the stlib csv module directly after it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have headers and want to pull out specific column data try

```
import csv
with open('csv_file.csv', 'rU') as csv_file:
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in csvreader:
            print("Rows: " + str(row))
            if row['header1'] == '1':
                print('Data: ' + row['header2'])
```

CSV File contents:

```
header1,header2,header3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Output:

```
Rows: {'header2': '2', 'header3': '3', 'header1': '1'}
Data: 2
Rows: {'header2': '5', 'header3': '6', 'header1': '4'}
```

If you have a lot of data adding headers can make your life easier or you will have to use csv.reader() and parse the contents and split as needed.

Comment: I dont have any headers in the file.The values are prefixed by a key and based on the event I have to take the specific values.When it was a normal csv file,with just values  I had created Dicts ,using csv reader and then based on the event I took the index and took the values.

Comment: The answer is not relevant as the OP wants to know how to parse a csv file without headers and also provided an example of csv file

Answer (score 0):

Use `for row in`[csv.reader()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader), then place an if and some elifs in the for loop.